# Errors in solar system plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I have encountered an error in this piece of code that tracks the location of planets and maps their positions in a 2D or 3D plot.

The errors are regarding the plotting of the 2D and 3D animation. The 2D animation fails to plot the individual points and the 3D animation fails to compile.

The required code snippets are as follows and must be saved with appropriate file names and in the same location or the code won't run.

Voyager 1_values.txt

```
825.5
1.989e30
5.972e24
5.683e26
1.898e27
6.691403977335315E-03
2.202627662224282E-02
4.216890028880711E-04
9.703073590971770E-01 
-2.864904318339970E-01
1.066427909013482E-04
8.067421617009274E-06
3.673201792957197E-08
-2.197071568474863E-07
2.375093302282981E-03
-4.397270119725996E-03
-6.428130544954251E-05
4.590127149769456E-03
1.643984412766133E-02
8.985886924997390E-07
9.693422765732221E-01
-2.888759358488555E-01
-7.089083396940953E-05
-3.766914208115172E-03
-4.385970127923834E-03
2.266658054908204E-04
-7.191296394438012E+00
5.703064547398564E+00
1.860205210308839E-01
-7.563034994845861E-03
1.388374837453606E-03
1.636332584494625E-04
7.023077014266478E-01
5.044885802251890E+00
-3.650827909007669E-02
```

Voyager 2_values.txt

```
825.5
1.989e30
5.972e24
5.683e26
1.898e27
1.018617820600348E-02
1.998609427696851E-02
1.902888687234539E-03
8.620811898118265E-01
-5.362815775434949E-01
6.254085137328873E-04
8.029313610091777E-06
-1.570146617228189E-07
-2.179903584404378E-07
 2.246309216105666E-03
-4.396294848083473E-03
-6.077909636341005E-05
8.802784907564254E-03
1.455442742467161E-02
-3.999157551260068E-08
 8.615157791605411E-01
-5.382505307629882E-01
-8.406626961973767E-05
-3.810770594695837E-03
-4.350834041096856E-03
2.277862628513098E-04
-7.130666351091540E+00
5.772950943135804E+00
1.823885596759469E-01
-7.536246065039235E-03
1.568985796886243E-03
1.622843968576739E-04
8.230978906159968E-01
5.021217065564969E+00
-3.911622055956051E-02
```

solar system_values.txt

```
1.024e26
7.342e22
8.958e20
-8.074327841694941E-06
-3.725217511481164E-06
2.325448967848458E-07
-5.137169516793444E-03
6.983299855954004E-03
6.057462903046038E-05
1.449291405719888E-02
-1.827765259617249E-02
-2.823248241000055E-03
-3.176293084594282E-01
-3.161184309540311E-01
2.324579306911361E-03
2.004342892467191E-02
-1.341908409616592E-03
-1.175244838741820E-03
-5.045585962890811E-02
-7.183332834232609E-01
-7.277242097534205E-03
1.671157447462403E-02
-2.700289160453826E-03
5.824994620501527E-07
-1.601628780716206E-01
-9.966051591509617E-01
1.102544734087047E-04
1.223764354247163E-02
8.849551026580525E-03
-1.146722346400340E-04
7.604677624850923E-01
-1.165066485435739E+00
-4.328057079261070E-02
7.029537038777072E-03
2.853229244535583E-03
-1.690714342107682E-04
1.705341949170244E+00
-4.869496044094564E+00
-1.795475506734141E-02
4.652759345938172E-03
2.532101808738509E-03
-2.293930487910554E-04
4.568910577877382E+00
-8.903395835510970E+00
-2.708098299127290E-02
-2.388074970251919E-03
2.963687068689659E-03
4.213596627021830E-05
1.584052114505656E+01
1.187548601597577E+01
-1.611099481036783E-01
5.940114776430491E-04
3.097117266024907E-03
-7.775939412356781E-05
2.934006870156765E+01
-5.855809639734187E+00
-5.555815243956886E-01
1.695277682863291E-02
-2.187979849573529E-03
-2.078160233904712E-05
-1.577157190376655E-01
-9.976382501635506E-01
-1.176323578276609E-04
6.037839150926329E-03
7.385490104984286E-03
-8.806930066949787E-04
2.275194256659004E+00
-1.844736378382702E+00
-4.785138675398960E-01
```

halley_values

```
1014E+11
1.989E+30
2.384439626393696E-04 
5.530007714164934E-04 
-2.631764370760927E-05
-2.027676638546926E+01 
2.668007253081516E+01 
-9.976082637145126E+00
-8.111436191102888E-06 
-3.568311631694483E-06 
2.328685240269625E-07
-5.040043543152710E-03 
7.027058275336635E-03 
5.778147806683835E-05
```

Main Programme

```
# Numerical resolution of the N-bodies problem

# Importing Libraries

import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import time 

# Functions

def import_files(system , time_day , step , t) :
    if system == 'Voyager 2' :
        name = ['Voyager 2','Sun','Earth','Saturn','Jupiter']
    elif system == 'solar system' :
        name = ['Sun','Mercury','Venus','Earth','Mars','Jupiter','Saturn','Uranus','Neptun','Moon','Ceres']
    elif system == 'halley' :
        name = ['Halley comet','Sun']
    elif system == 'Voyager 1' :
        name = ['Voyager 1','Sun','Earth','Saturn','Jupiter']
        
    n = len(name)  
    M = list()  
    T = np.zeros(( 6 * n , len(t)))
    with open(system + '_values.txt','r') as file :
            L = file.readlines()
            for i in range(n):
                M.append(float(L[i]))
            for i in range(n , 6 * n + n , 1) :
                T[i - n , 0] = float(L[i])
    file.close()
    
    return T , M , name , n
    

def Euler_explicite(T , t , pas , M , n , G) :
    for i in range(1,len(t) , 1) :
        T[: , i] = T[: , i - 1] + pas * F(T[: , i - 1] , M , n , G) # Recurrence formula of the explicit Euler method
        
    return T


def Runge_Kutta_2(T , t , pas , M , n , G) :
    for i in range(1 , len(t) , 1) :
        k1 = T[: , i - 1] + pas * F(T[: , i - 1] , M , n , G)
        T[: , i] = T[: , i - 1] + (pas / 2) * (F(T[: , i - 1] , M , n , G) + F(k1 , M , n , G)) # Recurrence formula of the Runge-Kutta method 2
        
    return T


def Runge_Kutta_4( T , t , pas , M , n , G) :
    for i in range(1,len(t) , 1) :
        k1 = pas * F(T[: , i - 1] , M , n , G)
        k2 = pas * F(T[: , i - 1] + (1 / 2) * k1 , M , n , G)
        k3 = pas * F(T[: , i - 1] + (1 / 2) * k2 , M , n , G)
        k4 = pas * F(T[: , i - 1] + k3 , M , n , G)
        T[:,i] = T[: , i - 1]+ (1 / 6) *(k1 + 2 * k2 + 2 * k3 + k4)   # Recurrence formula of the Runge-Kutta method 4
        
    return T

    
def F(Z , M , n , G) :
    K = np.zeros(6 * n) # Creation of an array of 6n rows of zeros that we will come after 
                    # Complete with the Tn + 1 values
    for i in range(0 , n , 1) :
        a = 0
        b = 0
        c = 0
        for j in range(0 , n , 1) :
            if i != j :
                a += (M[j] * (Z[6 * i + 3] - Z[6 * j + 3])) / ((Z[6 * i + 3] - Z[6 * j + 3]) ** 2 + (Z[6 * i + 4] - Z[6 * j + 4]) ** 2 + (Z[6 * i + 5] - Z[6 * j + 5]) ** 2) ** (3 / 2)
                b += (M[j] * (Z[6 * i + 4] - Z[6 * j + 4])) / ((Z[6 * i + 3] - Z[6 * j + 3]) ** 2 + (Z[6 * i + 4] - Z[6 * j + 4]) ** 2 + (Z[6 * i + 5] - Z[6 * j + 5]) ** 2) ** (3 / 2)
                c += (M[j] * (Z[6 * i + 5] - Z[6 * j + 5])) / ((Z[6 * i + 3] - Z[6 * j + 3]) ** 2 + (Z[6 * i + 4] - Z[6 * j + 4]) ** 2 + (Z[6 * i + 5] - Z[6 * j + 5]) ** 2) ** (3 / 2)


        a = - G * a
        b = - G * b
        c = - G * c        
                
                
        K[6 * i] = a
        K[6 * i + 3] = Z[6 * i]
        K[6 * i + 1] = b
        K[6 * i + 4] = Z[6 * i + 1]
        K[6 * i + 2] = c
        K[6 * i + 5] = Z[ 6 * i + 2]
      
    return K


def show_2D(n , T , name , methode) :
    plt.figure("Graphic Representation")
    for i in range(0 , n , 1) :  
        plt.plot(T[6 * i + 3 , :] , T[6 * i + 4 , :] , label = 'trajectory of {}'.format(name[i]))
        plt.plot(T[6 * i + 3 , 0] , T[6 * i + 4 , 0] , 'ko') # we trace the initial positions of each body by a black point
     
    plt.title('Numerical representation for the problem with {} bodies with the method of {}'.format(n , methode))
    plt.xlabel('X (in astronomical units)')
    plt.ylabel('Y (in astronomical units)')     
    plt.grid(linewidth = 0.5)
    plt.axis('equal')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()


def animation_2D(n , T , name , methode , time_annimation , step):
    show_2D(n , T , name , methode)
    nbr_var = []
    begin = time.time()
    end = time.time()
    
    for i in range(0 , n , 1):
        nbr_var.append(name[i])
        nbr_var[i], = plt.plot([] , [] , 'ko' , linewidth = 5)
        plt.axis('equal')
    for z in range(0 , len(t) , int(len(t) / 100)) :
        if time_annimation >= (end - begin) :
            for i in range(0 , n , 1) :
                nbr_var[i].set_data(T[6 * i + 3 , z] , T[6 * i + 4 , z])
                plt.axis('equal')
                plt.draw()
                plt.pause(step)
            end = time.time()
            
            
def show_3D(n , T , name , methode) :
    fig = plt.figure("Graphic Representation")
    ax = fig.gca(projection = '3d')
    for i in range(0 , n , 1) :  
        ax.plot(T[6 * i + 3 , :] , T[6 * i + 4 , :] , T[6 * i + 5 , :], label = 'trajectory of {}'.format(name[i]))
        ax.scatter(T[6 * i + 3 , 0] , T[6 * i + 4 , 0] , T[6 * i + 5 , 0])
        
    ax.set_xlabel('X (in astronomical units)')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y (in astronomical units)') 
    ax.set_zlabel('Z (in astronomical units)')
    plt.title('Numerical representation for the problem with {} bodies with the method of {}'.format(n , methode))
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()


def animation_3D(n , T , name , methode , time_annimation , step) :
    show_3D(n , T , name , methode)
    nbr_var = []
    begin = time.time()
    end = time.time()
    for i in range(0 , n , 1) :
        nbr_var.append(name[i])
        nbr_var[i], = plt.plot([] , [] , [] , 'ko' , linewidth = 5)  
    for z in range(0 , len(t) , int(len(t) / 100)) :
        if time_annimation >= (end - begin) :
            for i in range(0 , n , 1) :
                nbr_var[i].set_data(T[6 * i + 3 , z] , T[6 * i + 4 , z])
                nbr_var[i].set_3d_properties(T[6 * i + 5 , z])
                plt.draw()
                plt.pause(step)
            end=time.time()
            
# Constants

G = 1.4872 * 10 ** -34
methode = "Runge_Kutta_4" 
S = ['Voyager 2' , 'solar system' , 'halley' , 'Voyager 1']
systeme = S[1] 
time_day = 365 # one year
step = 0.1
time_annimation = 20 # seconds

# Main program

# Time scale
t = np.arange(0 , time_day , step)

# Importing data
T , M , name , n = import_files(systeme , time_day , step , t)

# Explicit Euler Method
#Z = Euler_explicite(T , t , step , M , n , G)

# Runge Kutta 2 Method 
#Z = Runge_Kutta_2(T, t, step , M , n , G)

# Runge Kutta 4 Method 
Z = Runge_Kutta_4(T, t, step, M, n , G)

# Display of the result in 2D
show_2D(n , Z , name , methode)

# Display of the result in 2D with animations
#animation_2D(n , T , name , methode , time_annimation , step)

# Display of the result in 3D
show_3D(n , Z , name , methode)

# Display of the result in 3D with animations
animation_3D(n , T , name , methode , time_annimation , step)
```

The error reads:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-bcf12163641c> in <module>
    203 
    204 # Display of the result in 3D with animations
--> 205 animation_3D(n , T , name , methode , time_annimation , step)
    206 
    207 

<ipython-input-8-bcf12163641c> in animation_3D(n, T, name, methode, time_annimation, step)
    151     for i in range(0 , n , 1) :
    152         nbr_var.append(name[i])
--> 153         nbr_var[i], = plt.plot([] , [] , [] , 'ko' , linewidth = 5)
    154     for z in range(0 , len(t) , int(len(t) / 100)) :
    155         if time_annimation >= (end - begin) :

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)
```

Comment: Why did you expect that `plt.plot` returns a 1-tuple?

Comment: The comma at the end of `nbr_var[i],` is probably a typo.